# Keras layer shape in plot_model()

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras to make a CNN, and I want to visualize the model with `plot_model()`.

When I look at the shape of the `Conv2d` layers, there is a thing that I can't figure out.

Let's say my `Conv2d` layer has kernel size `[8 x 8]`, stride is `[4 by 4]`, padding is `'same'` and I want 16 feature maps.

Input shape to this layer is `[None, 3, 160, 320]` and output is `[None,1,40,16]`.

'None' is samples, but what is 1 and 40? I guess 16 is number of feature maps?

Since I implemented `padding = 'same'`, shouldn't the image size out have the same width and height as input, or isn't this the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you're using "strides", you'll never have the same shape.

Your convolutional filter (which can be seen as a sliding window) is jumping four pixels in its sliding.

As a result, you get your final shape divided by 4 (and rounded up).

- 3/4 rounded up = 1
- 160/4 = 40
- 16 is the number of feature maps, indeed.

Comment: The raw image input data is [None, 3, 160, 320] which is [Samples, Color depth, height, width]. Am I applying convolution on the wrong dimensions? Does this indicate that the kernel is moving in the depth x height plane? Shouldn't the kernel move in the height x width dimensions?

Comment: Yes, this indicates that your dimensions are inverted. Keras standard `data_format` is `'channels_last'`: `(samples, height, width, channels)`. Notice the `16 features` at the last position.

Comment: You can change this if you want by adding the `data_format='channels_first'` in the layers, or changing the global setting in the `<user folder>\.keras\keras.json` file. --- `'channels_last'` has some advantages regarding certain classification problems, losses and activations that use the last dimension.

Comment: Does this also mean that [Comma.ai's open project](https://github.com/commaai/research/blob/master/train_steering_model.py) is not working as intended?

Comment: I don't know this project. But every library has its own format. Some image loaders already open images with channels last.

Comment: They probably changed the `keras.json` file. Thank you anyways!